# How do I fix laggy/choppy scrolling through images with Angular + Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, safari, ionic-framework

I'm building an iOS app with Phonegap, Ionic and Angular, and am having an issue where when I'm using ng-repeat with img src (or ng-src) the scrolling for a page of images becomes unacceptably jittery / laggy when scrolling past the images (you can imagine an Instagram or Facebook-like feed of images on a page). I seem to have the issue both when I load the page in Safari as well as on an iPhone. Chrome seems to be much better, so I perhaps it's a problem related to Safari?

I'm using standard ion-content tags. My ng-repeat is

```
<div ng-repeat="post in myPosts track by $index">
```

If I have the following code within the ng-repeat it works fine and the scrolling is perfect:

```
<img ng-src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/exampleS3Bucket/photos/somephoto.jpg">
```

However, when I try to use angular to have different images for each item in the repeated array I encounter the lag issue:

```
<img ng-src="{{post.image.url}}" >
```

I've tried using various ion-content scrolling settings and Bindonce, but nothing has helped so far. Appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 8):

You can try overflow-scroll="true" in ion-content tag.

Example:

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
```

It gave me huge performance boost.

Comment: Dude u saved my life thank for this, I recommend this solution.

Comment: guys saved me....I was using angular phonegap:The important part is i was using this for images that to inside ng-repeat as a ng-src,i was having no options where i am making mistake.But i don't know one css property saves my biggest lag

Comment: Looks like this solves lagging and improves speed..... Any idea why it's working? what exactly this improves?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the new [collection repeat feature](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/) of Ionic, it helps you increase the performance for huge lists.
[Here](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/mFygh) you have an extensive code example.

From the docs:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="ContentCtrl">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item my-item"
      collection-repeat="item in items"
      collection-item-width="'100%'"
      collection-item-height="getItemHeight(item, $index)"
      ng-style="{height: getItemHeight(item, $index)}">
      {{item}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should also ensure that you are not asking the device to scale down the images too much.... are your images really thumbnails?

Comment: Clawish, I'd prefer not to use it since collection repeat has a bunch of requirements about css etc that will involve refactoring code and I'm not convinced this is the issue since I'm seeing very glitchy/laggy scrolling when there are just a few images and posts (nowhere near a 100 let alone 1000). However, I'll try it out when I have time... Aaron I'll try your suggestion and let you know. The images are not meant to be thumbnails, they're meant to be images taking up the full-screen. Does downscaling cause glitchy scrolling?

Comment: Yes image resizing has a massive effect on performance. Particularly on older iPhones like the 4/4s. If possible make copies of the images at the exact size as required for your scrolling views for best performance

Comment: Got it, thanks Jamie & Aaron, I think that was the main issue. Not sure how to vote up your answers, if there's a way let me know!

Comment: How do you resize the images inside a Cordova app? Or did you resize them prior to run-time (within an image editing program)?

Comment: I'm using imagemagick on my server to resize images and then save them to S3 (by the way I'm also working on using the canvas to resize images in the app, not sure if this is what you're referring to)