# Ionic scroll Performance issue

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing application in which I have feeds or some timeline. here is my ng-repeat code:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in feeds" class="fd-feed-card">
    <div class="fd-feed-usr-img">
        <img ng-src="{{x.user.media[0].small}}" class="fd-img fd-img-br border-style">
    </div>

    <div class="ft-16 fd-feed-usr-name">
        <span><b>{{x.user.name}}</b></span><span class="ft-12 fd-feed-created-time plx prm">{{x.feed.createdTimeStamp | readableTime}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-style="imgStyle">
        <img ng-src="{{x.feed.media[0].medium}}" class="fd-img objectcover image-blur">
    </div>
    <div ng-if="x.feed.total_comments > 0 || x.feed.total_likes >0">
        <p class="mll"><span on-tap="openCommentModal(x.feed._id, $index, x.feed)" class="prm" ng-if="x.feed.total_comments > 0">{{x.feed.total_comments}} Comment</span><span ng-if="x.feed.total_likes>0" on-tap="openUserModal(x.feed._id)">{{x.feed.total_likes}} Likes</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="fd-feed-distance">
        <span class="plx prm ft-16">{{x.distance}} <span class="ft-10">mil</span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

here every feed contains username, userimage and `400*400px` image of feed and distance. after this im using ionic infinite scroll like this:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="getDashboardFeed()" distance="1%" ng-if="!noMoreFeedContent"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

in my javascript code, i am calling API with pagination having 5 feeds at a time. here it is my javascript code:

```
$scope.getDashboardFeed = function(start) {
    var _start = start || false;
    var params = {}
    params.offset = offset;
    params.limit = limit;
    Posts.getAllFeeds(params).success(function(res) {
            if (_start) {
                $scope.feeds = [];
            }
            if (res.data.length < limit) {
                $scope.noMoreFeedContent = true;
            } else {
                $scope.noMoreFeedContent = false;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
                var markerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(res.data[i].feed.location[0], res.data[i].feed.location[1]);
                var currentLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(res.data[i].location.location[0], res.data[i].location.location[1])
                var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markerPos, currentLatLng) * 0.000621371;
                res.data[i].distance = distance.toFixed(2);
                for (var j = 0; j < res.data[i].feed.likes.length; j++) {
                    if (uid == res.data[i].feed.likes[j].user) {
                        res.data[i].isLiked = true;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        res.data[i].isLiked = false;
                    }
                }
                $scope.feeds.push(res.data[i]);

            }

            offset = offset + limit;
            if (_start) {
                $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
            } else {
                $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
            }
        })
        .error(function(err) {

        })
};
```

im also calculating distance of every feed based on current location. and checking if i liked the post or not.

Now the problem is when feed is loaded to 25,30 , the scroll becomes laggy in my android . Im also using native scrolling given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875640/cordova-android-scrolling-performance-issues) ,

i have read also more blogs like [this](http://www.thomasmaximini.com/2015/01/12/improving-scroll-performance-for-lists-in-ionic-framework.html)

but i didnt get much help. I have to load 1000s of feeds here where every feed contains 400*400px picture.

i also tried collection-repeat. it didnot work either.

Is there any other approach I can try to fix my scroll perfomance? 
Anybody can help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, especially when using images in ng-repeat.

Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881285/how-do-i-fix-laggy-choppy-scrolling-through-images-with-angular-ionic/32922833#32922833)